Post Correction Multiplication Explained
I am reading "Guide to FPGA Implementation of Arithmetic Functions" by Jean-Pierre Deschamps, and on page 206 chapter 8.4.3 the book goes into Post Correction Multiplication, but I do not understand neither the utility nor the implementation and would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Let me obtain "Guide to FPGA Implementation of Arithmetic Functions" by Jean-Pierre Deschamps so I can read chapter 8.4.3. Gimme a sec.

Okay! :D In hindsight, I should have provided a Springer URL, I will next time, and thank you kindly @Velvet

Do you also supply the 181EUR to obtain the book so I can know what you are asking about?

(I will next time you can Edit you posts.)

Hi @MrGerber very cheeky but no dice, just for those who already have the textbook hehe

In short: Postcorrection Multiplication allows you to compute a product of two numbers using fewer hardware resources than a traditional multiplication, given that their product is within a range.
I'm not sure if the name "Postcorrection" is the best term for it.

For others, the book in question has the DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-2987-2
You can find the author's complete implementation on their github: https://github.com/sergev/Guide-to-FPGA-Implementation-of-Arithmetic-Functions/blob/master/chapter8/postcorrection_multiplier.vhd
In the following I'll try to explain the section of the book:
Given four binary signed integers: \$x,y,u\$ and \$v\$, where each is built up in the form of \$x=x_n x_{n-1} x_{n-2} \ldots x_0\$.
The integers \$x\$ and \$u\$ both have a length of \$n\$, where the integers \$y\$ and \$v\$ have a length of \$m\$.
Now assume that the term for \$z = x\cdot y + u + v\$ falls within the range of \$-B^{n+m+1} \le z \le B^{n+m+1}\$. Note: This is the main assumption this method makes. This is not generally applicable.
The author then claims that \$z\$ can be re-written as
$$z = \underbrace{\left(X_0 Y_0 + U_0+V_0\right) + x_n y_m B^{n+m}}_{\rightarrow x\cdot y + U_0 + V_0} - \underbrace{\left(x_n Y_0 + u_n\right)B^n}_{\text{factor for } u \text{ addition}} - \underbrace{\left(y_m X_0 + v_m\right)B^n}_{\text{factor for } v \text{ addition}}$$
where \$X_0, Y_0, U_0\$ and \$V_0\$ are the integers sans-sign bit: the naturals (e.g. \$X_0 = x_{n-1} x_{n-2} \ldots x_0\$, note the missing \$x_n\$ term).
Due to the previous assumption of the range of \$z\$, we can find that $$Z_0 = X_0 Y_0 + U_0 + V_0$$
This step is presented without motivation - I'm not sure how one would figure this out to be honest.
As we can see, the term consists only of simple multiplications and additions. None of which have to take special action regarding the sign bit.
The author doesn't explicitly mention this, but I assume the term for "post-correction" stems from the fact that we must re-construct the sign bit of \$z\$ from \$Z_0\$.
The author then proceeds to give a concrete example with \$B=2\$ and the additive integers \$u=v=0\$.
The author then proceeds to apply the previous term expansion and then simplifies the expression using NAND-gates.
If you compare the optimised implementation from Figure 8.16 (for \$n=3,m=2\$) with the previous implementation of Figure 8.15 (which is also smaller, only for \$m=n=2\$) you can see that the post-corrected implementation uses fewer multiplication elements (7 vs 16). However keep the assumption of the range limit in mind. The two circuits are not equivalent!

(Looks great. Refraining from voting for lack of access to book contents, only.)

Hi @playduck thank you for making this so digestible! Perhaps the logic for post correction operates on the same vein as carry-save adders? Since that also is post-correcting but for the carry term. Either way, thank you for making this multiplier implementation approachable for us have a great day
